# Highchart : using another myData for colume tooltip box

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Since i wanted to have some other values in my chart, therefore i try to do something like below

```
   series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
            stack: 'male',
            myData: 'firstPoint'
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5],
            stack: 'female',
            myData: 'secondPoint'
        }]
```

And want to display 'firstPoint' and 'secondPoint' in the tooltip box.

But it's return unidentify in the result

**Updated:**
Please see my demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/v96mbdbw/5/

> And the demo below here is for reference, which is a success example:
>        http://jsfiddle.net/dWDE6/874/

Comment: Hey, What you want to display total =???

Comment: Don't confuse youself, my friend, i just want to render the value in the field "myData"

Comment: So "myData : secondPoint" is the desire result...etc

Comment: Right now you have your myData in series, not point so you should to look for it inside your series object: http://jsfiddle.net/v96mbdbw/4/ If this will meet your requirements I will post it as an answer

Comment: can i have an array and display values one by one ? http://jsfiddle.net/v96mbdbw/5/